# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi lista solo recorra dentro del rectángulo?, Python

Tags: python, imagen, binario

Se desea que solo se grafique/dibujen los puntos ('+') y parábola dentro de la zona negra que está en el rectángulo.

Lo que se supone que se haciendo es que, se está generando la lista a lo largo del rectángulo para que de ésta forma se delimite un poco el área y que apesar de que haya más zonas negras solo se tome la del centro (la boquita) ya que se "se está delimitando" con el rectángulo.

Ésta primera parte del código según yo no están importante solo es para que tengán el código completo y se pueda visualizar como es que se está desarrollando todo.

Parte uno del código:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

image = cv2.imread('radio.jpg',0)
img = cv2.resize(image,(600,300))

hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

b=sum(hist)
objetivo = b/2
suma=0
numero=0
final=0

for i in hist:
    suma=suma+i
    numero=numero+len(i)
    final=numero+1
    #print('Final:',final)
    if suma > objetivo: 
       break
   
U=final-3
ResFinal=U*2
y=((30*ResFinal)/100)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,y,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

lista = []
    for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 3000 and area <  10000:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #print('El área es:',area)
        lista.append(area)
        resultado = sorted(lista, reverse=True)[0:-1]
        #print("Áreas encontradas:", resultado)
```

Parte dos del código:

```
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        rect= cv2.rectangle(th1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        #Puntos para la parábola
        #Coordenadas de pixeles
        vlxU=x 
        vlxL=x+w
        vlyU=y 
        vlyL=y+h
    
        pnx=list(range(0, len(rect[0])))
        pny=list(range(0, len(rect)))
        lx = random.choices(pnx, k=70)
        ly = random.choices(pny, k=70)

        lista_blanca = zip(lx, ly)
        lista_oscura = []

        #print("Examinar muestra aleatoria")
        for x, y in lista_blanca:
            pixel = rect[y][x]
            #print(f"Pixel({x}, {y}) = {pixel}")
            if pixel == 0:
                lista_oscura.append((x,y))
             
    
        #print("Listar lista oscura")
        lstx = []
        lsty = []
        for x, y in lista_oscura:
            pixel = rect[y][x]
            #print(f"Pixel({x}, {y}) = {pixel}")
            #print("Pixel{x} de oscura",[x])
            #print("Pixel{y} de oscura",[y])
            lstx.append(x)
            lsty.append(y)
            if len(lstx) and len(lsty) == 30:
                print('valores 30 de x ',lstx)
                print('valores 30 de y ',lsty)
        

            model = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(listax,listay, 2))
            polyline = np.linspace(150, 450, 450)
            plt.plot(listax,listay,'+r')
            plt.plot(polyline, model(polyline))
            plt.axis('off')
            plt.legend()
            plt.imshow(th1,cmap = 'gray')
            plt.title("Funciona")
                    plt.figure()

  
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

En la imagen se muestra como se están tomando los puntos('+') en todas las zonas negras e ignora completamente el hecho de que en la parte dos del código se le dice que sea a lo largo de rect para que de ahí es donde se tomen los puntos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es un elemento de lista 1? ¿Una tupla (x, y, valor_pixel)? ¿Cómo defines la zona oscura? ¿Es un rectángulo, un polígono o un área irregular definida por una lista de puntos (x, y)? Tal vez si publicas una ejemplo detallado se entienda mejor.

Comment: Hola! Vi tu pregunta de ayer... está relacionada, es la misma o es totalmente diferente? Si es la misma con otro enfoque, no abras N preguntas con lo mismo (puedes editarla y cambiarla como desees). Lo otro: revisa la indentación de tu código en la pregunta, que en python ya sabes que es muy importante

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta para la proxima vez Alfabravo, gracias (:

Comment: @CandidMoe Ya agregué más parte del código. Delimito el área con boudingRect y de ahí genero la lista para los 30 valores aleatorios dentro de esa área. Y creo la zona oscura no la tengo definida de alguna forma. Adjuntaré una imagen para explicarme mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Interpretación del problema**

Tienes una imagen que aquí representare como una lista de cadenas. Cada cadena representa una fila y cada carácter dentro de la fila representa un pixel. Los pixeles oscuros los represento con una 'x'; los pixeles blancos, con un espacio:

```
# +----> eje X
# |
# |
# v eje Y
imagen = [
"   x   xxxxx   xxx   xx     xxxx     x",
"  xxxx  xxxx      xx   xxxxx    xxxx  ",
"x     xx xxxx  xx     xxxxx   xxxxx  x",
"  xxx  xxxxxxx   xxxxxx   xxx  xxxxx  ",
" xx    xxxx xx xxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx  x  ",
"xxxx    xxxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx    xxxx  x",
"   x   xxxxx   xxx   xx     xxxx      ",
"  xxxx  xxxx      xx   xxxxx    xxxx x",
"x     xx xxxx  xx     xxxxx   xxxxx   ",
"  xxx  xxxxxxx   xxxxxx   xxx  xxxxx x",
" xx    xxxx xx xxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx  x  ",
"xxxx    xxxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx    xxxx  x",
]
```

Entonces, el pixel en la coordenada (x, y) queda representado por `imagen[y][x]`. Tengo que dar vuelta las coordenadas X e Y por un problema de representación simplemente.

La coordenada X varía desde 0 a 37 (izquierda a derecha) y la coordenada Y desde 0 a 11 (arriba hacia abajo).

Siguiendo tu código, genero una lista de todas las coordenadas X posibles en `pnx`. Igual para la coordenadas Y, con `pny`. Ningún misterio ahí.

```
pnx=list(range(0, len(imagen[0])))
pny=list(range(0, len(imagen)))
```

A continuación hago una lista de 10 coordenadas aleatorias:

```
lx = random.choices(pnx, k=10)
ly = random.choices(pny, k=10)
```

En `lista_blanca` tengo una lista de 10 tuplas. Cada tupla contiene una coordenada (x, y). Genero estas tuplas usando la función `zip`, que une ambas listas:

```
lista_blanca = zip(lx, ly)
```

La lista oscura parte vacía:

```
lista_oscura = []
```

Ahora recorro la lista blanca para obtener el valor de cada pixel en la coordenada correspondiente:

```
print("Examinar muestra aleatoria")
for x, y in lista_blanca:
    pixel = imagen[y][x]
    print(f"Pixel({x}, {y}) = {pixel}")
    if pixel == 'x':
        lista_oscura.append((x,y))
```

Recordemos que el pixel(x,y) está en `imagen[y][x]`.

En `pixel` tengo el valor del pixel, que puede ser 'x' (oscuro) o ' ' (blanco). Si es un pixel oscuro, agrego las coordenadas a la lista oscura.

Eso sería todo.

**Comprobación**

Aquí está el código completo, más una comprobación de los resultados:

```
import random

# +----> eje X
# |
# |
# v eje Y
imagen = [
"   x   xxxxx   xxx   xx     xxxx     x",
"  xxxx  xxxx      xx   xxxxx    xxxx  ",
"x     xx xxxx  xx     xxxxx   xxxxx  x",
"  xxx  xxxxxxx   xxxxxx   xxx  xxxxx  ",
" xx    xxxx xx xxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx  x  ",
"xxxx    xxxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx    xxxx  x",
"   x   xxxxx   xxx   xx     xxxx      ",
"  xxxx  xxxx      xx   xxxxx    xxxx x",
"x     xx xxxx  xx     xxxxx   xxxxx   ",
"  xxx  xxxxxxx   xxxxxx   xxx  xxxxx x",
" xx    xxxx xx xxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx  x  ",
"xxxx    xxxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx    xxxx  x",
]

pnx=list(range(0, len(imagen[0])))
pny=list(range(0, len(imagen)))
lx = random.choices(pnx, k=10)
ly = random.choices(pny, k=10)

lista_blanca = zip(lx, ly)
lista_oscura = []

print("Examinar muestra aleatoria")
for x, y in lista_blanca:
    pixel = imagen[y][x]
    print(f"Pixel({x}, {y}) = {pixel}")
    if pixel == 'x':
        lista_oscura.append((x,y))

print("Listar lista oscura")
for x, y in lista_oscura:
    pixel = imagen[y][x]
    print(f"Pixel({x}, {y})={pixel}")
```

produce:

```
Examinar muestra aleatoria
Pixel(29, 8) =  
Pixel(31, 11) = x
Pixel(25, 3) =  
Pixel(0, 1) =  
Pixel(36, 9) =  
Pixel(6, 3) =  
Pixel(12, 8) = x
Pixel(9, 6) = x
Pixel(34, 4) =  
Pixel(25, 0) =  
Listar lista oscura
Pixel(31, 11)=x
Pixel(12, 8)=x
Pixel(9, 6)=x
```

Para referencia, aqui está la imagen con sus coordenadas

```
---0123456789*123456789*123456789*1234567
00    x   xxxxx   xxx   xx     xxxx     x
01   xxxx  xxxx      xx   xxxxx    xxxx  
02 x     xx xxxx  xx     xxxxx   xxxxx  x
03   xxx  xxxxxxx   xxxxxx   xxx  xxxxx  
04  xx    xxxx xx xxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx  x  
05 xxxx    xxxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx    xxxx  x
06    x   xxxxx   xxx   xx     xxxx      
07   xxxx  xxxx      xx   xxxxx    xxxx x
08 x     xx xxxx  xx     xxxxx   xxxxx   
09   xxx  xxxxxxx   xxxxxx   xxx  xxxxx x
10  xx    xxxx xx xxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx  x  
11 xxxx    xxxxxxx  xxx xxxxxx    xxxx  x
```

Comment: Oye @Candid Moe que gran explicación realmente, gracias. Solo me queda como pregunta en el if que se tiene la condicion la pones  == 'x' dado que es la parte oscura, cierto? Ahí debo de cambiar yo ese valor de 'x' por el 255 para que me pueda dar la lista de la parte oscura? es que llevo un rato intentandolo y no me funciona pero creo que es por esa 'x' sin embargo no estoy segura.

Comment: De igual forma me preguntaba como podria hacer para tomar solo el área delimitada por el rectangulo porque si no se reduce un poco podria tomar valores de otra parte que no sea la parte maxilar. De igual forma edité el código de arriba y ya lo escribí completo a como yo lo tengo para que sea mas sencillo entender el enfoque.

Comment: @SheccidSeleneCortésServín. Efectivamente, debes cambiar el 'x' por el valor que te interesa. Ese valor depende de los valores que toman los pixeles en el problema real. Tal vez la parte oscura tiene valores entre 200 y 255, por ejemplo, y haya que comparar contra un rango. Hay que ajustar el área a considerar obviamente; use una imagen chica por simplicidad.

Comment: ya me generó la lista oscura!!! Muchas gracias de verdad. Lo único que me pregunto es ¿como puedo delimitar las listas al área que tengo dentro del rectángulo? para trabajar solo con el área maxilar.

Comment: @SheccidSeleneCortésServín. No conozco el módulo cv2; ahí no te puedo ayudar.

Comment: No, no te preocupes con la ayuda que me diste es un gran avance!! Muchas gracias en verdad (: